# beforeEncode and afterDecode not executed on Page

Tags: swift, vapor

I have a `Post` model with `beforeEncode` set:

```swift
extension Post {
    func beforeEncode() throws {
        print("1")
    }
}
```

This works as expected when my route returns `Post` or `EventLoopFuture<Post>`. The `1` is printed to the console. It doesn't work when returning `EventLoopFuture<Page<Post>>` however, so the `1` is never printed.

I thought that this was because the posts of the page never get encoded but the page itself, so I extended `Page`:

```swift
extension Page where T: Content {
    mutating func beforeEncode() throws {
        print("2")
        self = try self.map { (item: T) throws -> T in
            var item: T = item
            try item.beforeEncode()
            return item
        }
    }
}
```

This does not get executed either but the default implementation of `beforeEncode` does when the following route is called:

```swift
app.get("route") { (request: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<Page<Post>> in
    return Post.query(on: request.db).paginate(for: request)
}
```

Neither `1` nor `2` is printed to the console.

How do I do it so the `beforeEncode` method gets executed on every post of the page?

Why is the default implementation of `beforeEncode` called and not the one added by my own extension of `Page`?

(I know that I could just map the `EventLoopFuture` and call `beforeEncode` manually on each item of the page but that's not what I want)